# mySQL query across multiple schemas

Tags: mysql

I have a multi-schema structure (same table across all schemas).

Here is how I can fetch all the schemas:

```
select table_schema from information_schema.tables where table_name = 'messages' and TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```

This query is for a join between 'messages' table across two tables-

```
select *, '1' as customer from customer_1.messages union select *,  '2' as customer from customer_2.messages
```

How do I use the perform the above query for all the schemas from the first query? Need not be a join. Could be anything that helps me return the results across all schemas.

Note: There could be 5000-10000 schemas

Comment: I don't envy you one little bit.

Comment: Use dynamic SQL (Prepared Statement).

Comment: @Akina any resource/link I can check? I'm looking for a pure mySQL based solution. Cannot use server language to generate it.

Comment: But you could create stored procedure, and build the query and execute it. Can you use procedures?

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili yes potentially I could. Could you give me a headstart?

Comment: You already got the answer, that's what I meant, something like that.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
DELIMITER @@;

CREATE PROCEDURE join_all_data()
BEGIN
    SET @counter := 0;
    SELECT GROUP_CONCAT('select *, ',
                        @counter := @counter + 1,
                        ' as customer from ',
                        table_schema,
                        '.messages'
                        SEPARATOR ' UNION ALL ')
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        WHERE table_name = 'messages' 
          AND table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
        INTO @sql;
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DROP PREPARE stmt;
END
@@;

DELIMITER ;

CALL join_all_data;
```

Comment: Unable to execute this for some reason. Gives 4 errors. Using mySQL 8.

Comment: And is it possible to create a procedure and then a VIEW based on this?

Comment: @AlecSmart 1) The answer was edited - test last version. 2)  Have you reassigned the delimiter? 3) Post error messages.

Comment: @AlecSmart No, you cannot use procedure as a query rows source.

Comment: 11:49:09 PREPARE stmt FROM @sql Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 0.044 sec

Comment: This is giving an error- "SET @counter := 0;" along with "    EXEC stmt;
    DROP stmt;
END"

Comment: @AlecSmart You must reassign the delimiter! I'll update shortly... done.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209594/discussion-between-alec-smart-and-akina).

Comment: FYI you don't need to make a stored procedure to use prepared statements. You can use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` directly in one's MySQL session.

Comment: @BillKarwin For this to be true, you MUST GUARANTEE that all statements will be executed in the same connection. If you use connection pool or if the connection will break and be restored then the process will fail.